# How can I get a Windows client not in the domain to get dns from the DC?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, windows-7

I have **Server 2012** as Domain controller and **DNS server**.

Now if I have a machine joined to the domain, they get all **servers names** defined in dns zone.

I have a Windows 7 client which is not joined to the domain, but I want it to get the IP of the DNS servers.

I tried manually putting the IP `192.168.0.100` in the DNS of the network adapter, but it does not get the IP of the DNS servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When not a part of the domain, you need to use the FQDN of the host you are trying to resolve. Example:

A server named app01 on domain.lab with ip 192.168.0.69 being pinged from a machine on the same network, but not in the domain.

ping app01
 - host cannot be resolved

ping app01.domain.lab
- Reply from 192.168.0.69: time=blah blah blah

Comment: can't i use the dns server to be server 2008 for all computers on network. does not matter if they are part of domain or not. i mean for e,g i mean for `app01` the window 7 computer will query dns server which will be server 2008 , which then converts ti ip. currently i use my router gateway as my dns server

Comment: You "can" set it up to use any dns server you want, but the implementation will vary greatly based on your specifc situation. Your description of your current environment will need to be a lot more robust to get a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a non-domain joined computer to resolve internal names, you should be putting the domain controller (which has DNS on it) as the DNS server and setting the DNS prefix to whatever your domain name is. Even computers not on the domain will still be able to work with the DNS server.

What *won't* work is other computers resolving the name of the non-joined machine since it won't be in DNS, but that wasn't your requirement.

Comment: I tried that. i put the dns server as my DC. but my computer still can't resolve the internal ip. is there any way to check if my dns server is receiving any query from my computer

Comment: Yes, `nslookup someinternalhost 10.x.x.x` where 10.x.x.x is the IP address of your DNS server. You may need to use the FQDN if you don't have the prefix set.

Comment: thanks nathan , its working now. can i add two DNS on winod0w 7 so that first my computer goes to DNS server of router , and if that does not find any ip for host , then it asks for my DC to gte internal ip. I find that DNS resolution has slowed down the internet speed if i use internal